# Replace a specific part of a string that includes a variable in objective C

Tags: objective-c, string, variables, find, nsregularexpression

I've been spending hours trying to figure this out with no luck.
I have a string, call it *FileContent*, that holds the content of a file with UTF-8 encoding that I need to modify.

This *FileContent* has a specific section with a variable that I need to find, replace and then overwrite the original file with. I know how to replace the section once it is found and then overwrite the original file, but I struggle to find the section which has the variable itself.

The variable is made of **random numbers and letters with random length** to uniquely identify an individual user's session.

This is how the variable appears in the section of the file that is read into *FileContent*:

```
+option1 (variable) +option2
```

The surrounding text (+option1 and +option2) and whitespaces are constant, making it easy to locate manually. This section is part of a longer line that must be left intact.

I've tried NSRegularExpression:regularExpressionWithPattern: with a variety of wildcards, using \ to escape "+", but it always returns:

> The value “+option1 ... +option2” is invalid.

I tried all the wildcards from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression?language=objc) and various combinations of them as well that I found in other answered questions eg.

```
".*\+option1 (.*) \+option2.*".
```

Is NSRegularExpression not appropriate for this task?
Should I be using NSRange or NSScanner instead, perhaps something completely different?

Comment: Since it's simple and constant as you say, why not just use rangeOfString to find the start and end?

Comment: "I've tried NSRegularExpression:regularExpressionWithPattern: with a variety of wildcards, using \ to escape "+", but it always returns:" - edit your question and show what you've tried, both the regular expression and the code you use to create it and perform the match. People cannot help you fix your mistake unless they can see what you've done!

Comment: @johnelemans thanks for pointing in the right direction! Using rangeOfString does indeed solve my problem.

Comment: @CRD I edited it with an example, but basically spent a few hours going through the official documentation and experimenting with whatever made (or did not make) sense. Using **rangeOfString** instead however does work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John Elemans mentioned, if +option1 and +option2 is fixed and UNIQUE, you can simply use rangeOfString to do this. First, you need to find the index of both:

```
// FileContent now holds ".... +option1 yourString +option2 ...."

int idx1 = [FileContent rangeOfString:@"+option1"].location;
int idx2 = [FileContent rangeOfString:@"+option2"].location;
int len2 = [@"+option2" length];

if ((idx1>=0)&&(idx2>=0)) {
   NSString *str= [FileContent substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(idx1, idx2+len2-idx1)];
   // now str holds "+option1 yourString +option2"

   // split this into array
   NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

   // now array arr has [+option1,yourString,+option2]
   // So you can get your string by arr[1];
   NSLog(@"MyString %@",arr[1]);
}
```

Do note that if the option1 and 2 name are changed or their order is changed in anyway, this will break. Also note I have not tested this code. It might break at the nsmakerange area... do check the index/length properly.

Comment: Thanks, it works! The only warning it throws is **Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'** for idx1, 2 and len2 but I'm fine with that, I can actually use this in other parts of the code as well to make the program more robust! Thanks again!

Comment: ah. you can try change int to long that should remove the warning.

Comment: changing **int** to **long** does indeed remove the warning, thank you!